# DIV with max-height not expanding

Tags: html, css

I've made a drop-down list which attaches to a text input, and the list which appears beneath has a header and footer row, and scrolling content in between. JS fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/tpgjjh81/3/

It works great, except I'd like the drop-down to have a flexible height, depending on its content, up to a specified max-height. However, if I change:

```
DIV.dropdown {
    ...
    height: 100px;
    ...
}
```

to:

```
DIV.dropdown {
    ...
    max-height: 100px;
    ...
}
```

...then the "content" part of the list doesn't show at all when the drop-down appears, only the header and footer rows. The DIV's within have `height: 100%` so I would have thought these would push the outer DIV to its max-height but it doesn't appear to be working?

edit: I've also tried adding `height: auto` alongside the `max-height` but it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: max-height does not change the height of the element, hence why the height is not cascading. All that max-height does is not letting the element grow taller than the specified height.

Comment: Can you please make a [Fiddle](www.jsfiddle.net) or share your whole related code?

Comment: I haven't actually used it in any full code yet, just testing it out beforehand - all I have so far is what's in the JS fiddle above

Comment: I've added a fiddle, and answer below. This should solve your issue: https://jsfiddle.net/tpgjjh81/5/ Please let me know how you get on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/tpgjjh81/22/

The main issue was to do with the `DIV.scroll_inner` having `absolute` positioning with `0` edges (to fill the `scroll_outer` container).

Let the outer container control its own content, and limit the inner content's height to `max-height: 100px`.

Essentially, what you are looking for is something like this:

```css
DIV.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

DIV.dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  clear: left;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

DIV.list_container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

DIV.header,DIV.footer {
  display: table-row;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

DIV.scroll_outer {
  display: table-row;
  height: auto;
  background-color: white;
}

DIV.scroll_inner {
   overflow: auto;
   max-height: 100px;
}
```

**EDIT** I've also removed some now unnecessary properties from the CSS, and updated this above, and in the fiddle. This should at least get you off the ground.

Best of luck in your project! :)

Comment: Come to think of it - there's a few CSS properties you can clean up, as they're not required (e.g. `position: relative` on the `scroll_outer` class, along with some other). But I'll let you figure this out, I hope this at least gets you off the ground :)

Comment: That's done it, thanks! I took the `height` and `max-height` off `DIV.dropdown` as the inner content was overlapping the outer's border, and just left `max-height` on `DIV.scroll_inner`.

Comment: You're welcome, @Iain - I've updated the answer, and the fiddle with some properties stripped out - just for clarity for anyone else using this :) (I realise there are probably more, but that's more fun for you!)

Comment: I seem to have left in bits from trying all sorts of combinations before resorting to stack overflow!

Comment: This is tidy compared to a lot of code-spaghetti I've seen! Just remember: one change (within reason) at a time; undo it if you have no luck. Good luck in your project :)

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up your css. Not sure why you were using display table and setting up the height etc. Just hide the parent overflow and set child overflow to scroll and that should do it.

Also I moved the border to outer container so it is not cut off.

```js
is_visible = false;


function Toggle() {
 is_visible = !is_visible;
  
  document.getElementById("dropdown").style.display = (is_visible ? "block" : "none");
}
```

```css
DIV.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

DIV.dropdown {
  display: none;
    position: absolute;
    clear: left;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    overflow: scroll;
}

DIV.list_container {
      display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 0px;
  
}

DIV.header,DIV.footer {
  display: block;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

DIV.scroll_outer {
  display: block;

  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
}

DIV.scroll_inner {
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" size="50" value="Click me" onclick="Toggle()" />
  <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown">
    <div class="list_container">
      <div class="header">Header</div>
      <div class="scroll_outer">
        <div class="scroll_inner">
        Item 1<br />
        Item 2<br />
        Item 3<br />
        Item 4<br />
        Item 5<br />
        Item 6<br />
        Item 7
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used `display:table` and `table-row` to fix the header and footer at the top and bottom of the list, without, the header scrolls off the top / the footer doesn't appear until scrolling to the end

Answer (score -1):

```
height: auto;
max-height: 100px;
overflow: auto;
```

Comment: It does for me, I have updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tpgjjh81/7/